# Дублируются названия классов при генерации из XSD

Tags: xsd, jaxb

У меня есть XML, из которого я генерирую XSD схему.

Вот исходный XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <GetWizard2>
    <row allowlistvehicles="false" automatic="false" conditionid="1" determined="false" name="Region" type="">
      <options>
        <row key="$WiVI$" value="America" />
        <row key="$WiVK$" value="Asia" />
        <row key="$WiVL$" value="Europe" />
        <row key="$WiVN$" value="Japan" />
      </options>
    </row>
  </GetWizard2>
</response>
```

Вот сгенерированная схема:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="response">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GetWizard2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="row">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="options">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="allowlistvehicles"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="automatic"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="conditionid"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="determined"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

В результате получается два элемента с названием row:

```
<xs:element name="row">
<xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
```

Генерирую схемы плагином jaxb2-maven-plugin получается вот такой класс (лишний код удален):

```
public class Response {
    public static class GetWizard2 {
        public static class Row {
            public static class Options {
                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected List<Response.GetWizard2 .Row.Options.Row> row;
                @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                @XmlType(name = "")
                public static class Row {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка при сборке:

```
class ...Response.GetWizard2.Row is already defined in class ...Response.GetWizard2
```

Ругается на дублирование класса class Row

Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что схема генерировалась неправильно. Попробовал http://xml.mherman.org/ - схема генерируется без дублирования имен.